# Circuit image resolution is poor

Tags: support, circuitlab

In the circuit I just posted here:

[RS485 termination: AC + failsafe + parallel + bidirectional](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321607/rs485-termination-ac-failsafe-parallel-bidirectional)

It's fairly wide. The thumbnail shown in the question is low-res and blurry, which isn't the end of the world; I would expect that SE have a feature whereby you click on the image and a better-resolution popup is shown. However, clicking does nothing, and visiting the "simulate this circuit" link requires an active CircuitLab membership.

So how should we expect that a circuit of any significant complexity be well-rendered for this site? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Even worse is when you make a small circuit and it blows up to fill the whole page.

Comment: Six years later, still an issue.